# How can I efficiently build a near-full block in regtest?

Tags: regtest

I want to build near-full blocks in regtest.

I have written a script that does the job (on bitcoin core v24.0rc3), but it's too slow to be practical for my use case:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

BCLI="./bitcoin-cli -regtest"
DAEMON="./bitcoind -regtest"

# Start from a clean node
$BCLI stop
sleep 2
rm -rf ~/.bitcoin/regtest
$DAEMON
sleep 2

set -eo pipefail

$BCLI -named createwallet wallet_name="miner" load_on_startup=false
mineraddress=$($BCLI getnewaddress)
$BCLI generatetoaddress 1000 $mineraddress
i=0
time while [ $i -lt 100 ]
do
    newaddress=$($BCLI getnewaddress)
    $BCLI sendtoaddress $newaddress 1
    i=$((i+1))
done
$BCLI generatetoaddress 1 "$mineraddress"
```

There are a number of problems with this script:

- It's very slow, creating just ~10 transactions per second
- It's getting slower as more txs are created
- I have to generate lots of blocks (1000 instead of eg 101) to avoid hitting the limit of 25 chained mempool transactions, which further slows down the script.
- The above script creates just 100 txs for now just to measure its performance, but in reality I'd like to make ~7000 txs or more.

Can I improve this more than by just a constant factor?

Comment: Ideally you want to create the maximum number of UTXOs you can in each block so you can spend from each of them and create multiple UTXOs for each spent TXO in the next block right? A tree of UTXO spends. A chain of 25 transactions resulting in only one UTXO doesn't help much as you say.